# LibreOffice 4.4.4.3 crashes Unity (12.04 LTS)

Tags: 12.04, unity, graphics, libreoffice

For close to the last year, I have had problems with LibreOffice randomly crashing my Unity desktop in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  Today, I found a consistency to the problem and recorded a video to show what it is.

[LibreOffice Crashes Unity](https://youtu.be/8blLBJaxGkU)

Once I was able to consistently repeat the problem I made a video.

I don't know if this is the only cause, but when I go to change text color in Impress, (or word processor and spread sheet) the unity bar and the top task bar hide.  They are still there, but it doesn't all work.

I can eventually get out of the problem by using the workspaces changer, but sometimes it is a PITA.

I have searched for the problem and solution, but I don't see any threads (here or Google) that address my specific problem.

Please watch the video as a picture really is worth a thousand words here.

I am guessing this is reportable as a bug, but I couldn't find my way around bugzilla well enough to report it.

Does anyone know of a solution?

Thank you
Buck

Comment: Have you tried starting `soffice --impress` from a command line, and seeing if any error messages come up?

Comment: Thank you,

I just tried that.  It came up, did it's normal thing and I quit.  All I got was the line I entered and a new line waiting for a command.  :(

Comment: Did you find out how to fix this? I am using Libreoffice 5+ on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and whenever I use the font bg color in Calc the same thing happens.

Comment: @SuvP Unfortunately, no.  I upgraded to 14.04LTS and lost the problem.